How can I improve my code to obtain switching off the shapes which are visible on the buttons above each time I press one of those buttons
I want to change my code to the form I could obtain switching off each of two other shapes each time I press one of these buttons. Now when I press on more than one button the shapes remain placed one on another and I want to cancel them so only one shape will be visible related to current button and when I press another button this shape should vanish. In other words, I want to switch on each shape without remain of another shape.
I was trying to change my code, but I don't know how to do it. I was trying to apply setTimeout but this was not working as I wanted.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>shapes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="objectchange.css">
</head>
<body>
    <button class="button-1"><div class="circle"></div>Circle</button>
    <button class="button-1"><div class="rectangle"></div>Rectangle</button>
    <button class="button-1"><div class="square"></div>Square</button>
    <script src="objectchange.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

body{
    background-color:aliceblue;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.button-1{
    padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color:rgb(50,50,50);
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    border-radius:15px;
    margin:10px;
    border:none;
    
}
.button-1:hover{
    background-color:rgb(100,100,100);
}
.circle{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:30px; height:30px;
    border:3px solid white;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;margin-bottom:18px;
    
}
.rectangle{
    border-radius:7px;
    width:50px; height:30px;
    border:3px solid white;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;margin-bottom:18px;
}
.square{
    border-radius:7px;
    width:30px; height:30px;
    border:3px solid white;
    display:block;
    margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;margin-bottom:18px;  
}
.big-circle{
    position:absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:200px; height:200px;
    border:6px solid black;
    top:50%;left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.big-rectangle{
    position:absolute;
    width:400px; height:200px;
    border:6px solid black;
    top:50%;left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.big-square{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px; height:200px;
    border:6px solid black;
    top:50%;left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}

const button = document.getElementsByClassName('button-1');
    button[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
    const circle = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(circle).classList.add('big-circle');
}); 
 button[1].addEventListener('click', function(){
    const rectangle = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(rectangle).classList.add('big-rectangle');
});
button[2].addEventListener('click', function(){
    const square = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(square).classList.add('big-square');
});


I wonder how setTimeoutwas of any help in removing an element from dom before adding a new one (by the way)

You could simply use a  function shapeDraw() as callback for click:event  that takes an argument className. className will be the class of the button clicked. Based on the className your function will add desired class to the shapeDiv element and remove other classes from it. Also you do not need to add event listener manually to each button, simply use a for loop to loop through and add eventListener to each element of your node-List named button which you initialized in the beginning.


const button = document.getElementsByClassName('button-1');
const shapeDiv = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(shapeDiv);

function drawShape(className) {
  if (className.contains("circle")) {
    shapeDiv.classList.add("big-circle")
    shapeDiv.classList.remove("big-rectangle", "big-square");
  } else if (className.contains("rectangle")) {
    shapeDiv.classList.remove("big-square", "big-circle");
    shapeDiv.classList.add("big-rectangle");
  } else if (className.contains("square")) {
    shapeDiv.classList.remove("big-rectangle", "big-circle");
    shapeDiv.classList.add("big-square");
  }
}
for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => drawShape(event.target.classList))
};
body {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.button-1 {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: none;
}

.button-1:hover {
  background-color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.rectangle {
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.square {
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 3px solid white;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}

.big-circle {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 6px solid black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.big-rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 6px solid black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.big-square {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 6px solid black;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
<button class="button-1"><div class="circle"></div>Circle</button>
<button class="button-1"><div class="rectangle"></div>Rectangle</button>
<button class="button-1"><div class="square"></div>Square</button>



